# What does this "3-line to column" icon indicate about an object in SQL Developer?

Tags: sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer, under Tables, almost all of my tables are just a *normal* table icon, however, every so often I come across a table that has the icon/image shown below. I wasn't around when some of these tables were created, so I'm just curious as to what this table has that is causing the icon to be displayed like so.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference [Table icons?](https://community.oracle.com/message/3510735#3510735)

> A table icon with horizontal cuts denotes partitioned table. A table
>   with tree branches on the left is index organized one.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Questioned Icon]  Indexed Organized Table

See here: http://www.peasland.net/2017/05/02/sql-developer-icons/